# Regex lookahead & lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I am trying regex to extract data backwards using lookahead & lookbehind.

In the below, I am interested in only `column store error`, i.e., with pattern as `: search table error:`, I need to extract string until previous `:`.

```
Error processing. Reason: Exception: Job aborted due to failure: xxxxx (asasdasd): com.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [123]
```

I am currently stuck with `(?<=:)(.*?)(?=(: search table error))`. This is extracting from the first occurrence of `:` from beginning.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
:\s*([^:]*?)\s*: search table error
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/z4Dm5z/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]*?                   any character except: ':' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  : search table error     ': search table error'
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##bVDBTsMwDL33K556aicUsY0DioSQRnfZEXErBaWp1wW1TeSkqHx9SQuTOGD58GQ/P/vZfYWLHfbzbHpnOYApYWppwgM4la9@k5Vvsto85hFKeFKsLwiq7gjEbDlNAvnw7gPHifS4lODYavLeDK3AMylvB4njpMkFs8CTraHquIwaNCMhWJyV6UYmiWkJZMor38TMJbTtRVOLj6bWgq4iXpyKw1PB5pP4j3JxeKF43tKTKHe3d/fVItCN/QAfLP/e/J8PCZTb3b5Kk16F2Ir2SfzQsvUhN7gazRNzxsqSCWI4NkPI1oJo2Y4u2@b5PH8D)**:

```py
import re
regex = r":\s*([^:]*?)\s*: search table error"
test_str = "Error processing. Reason: Exception: Job aborted due to failure: xxxxx (asasdasd): com.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [123]"
match = re.search(regex, test_str)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

**Results**: `column store error`

---

Also:

```py
(?<=:)[^:]*(?=:\s+search\s+table\s+error:)
```

See [this regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/z4Dm5z/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^:]*                    any character except: ':' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search                   'search'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    table                    'table'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    error:                   'error:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

with **[Python code](https://tio.run/##TVDBasMwDL3nK0RO9jbM1u4wTEOhSy89jt2ybDiOmngksZGdkX195qQEJgQST8/PenK/obXDfp5N7ywFIEwIG5wgA0rZ8ZBJXnzK8o4dM/nh7z0q0m1sgqo6jBWJLEmeJgF9@PKB4sP0vIDgyGr03gyNgDdU3g4SzpNGF8zSXmwFqop/Yg31iBAsXJXpRkIJ0xLAlFe@jsklaNuLuhLfdaUFbiJeXPLTa07mB@mfcn56R93CMpNQ7B6fX8pFoBv7AXywhHDbGm5uYPWyYVA87fZlmvQqxFG8Aoobja13eYDNKE/MFVaWTCCGIzMEtgKiITs6xkWkmVj5PP8B)** like

```py
import re
regex = r"(?<=:)[^:]*(?=:\s+search\s+table\s+error:)"
test_str = "Error processing. Reason: Exception: Job aborted due to failure: xxxxx (asasdasd): com.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [123]"
match = re.search(regex, test_str)
if match:
    print(match.group().strip())
```